# How can I drop all tables in my database?

Tags: mysql

How can I drop all tables in my database ?

1) In one MYSQL command

2) Without destroying and creating the database ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
mysqldump -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] --add-drop-table --no-data [DATABASE] | grep ^DROP | mysql -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] [DATABASE]
```

Neat little trick, and it works for me.

Originally suggested [here](http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/10-10-2006/mysql-drop-all-tables).

Comment: Note that this is to be run from system command line, not as MySQL statement.

Comment: I can only run mysql statements, so I guess this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name INTO #tables from sys.objects where type = 'U'
while (SELECT count(1) FROM #tables) &amp;gt; 0
begin
declare @sql varchar(max)
declare @tbl varchar(255)
SELECT top 1 @tbl = name FROM #tables
SET @sql = 'drop table ' + @tbl
exec(@sql)
DELETE FROM #tables where name = @tbl
end
DROP TABLE #tables;
```

Got this from [here](http://www.fragmentedcode.com/2008/04/22/sql-server-drop-tables-database-quickly/). Quick and dirty, it says. It certainly is dirty. ;-)

Comment: it doesn't work.. it says synatax error. I guess because of: &amp;gt; 0

Comment: More likely because it's not MySQL. A procedure like this can be created in MySQL, using information.schema in place of sys.objects (and of course MySQL compatible syntax for variables)

Answer (score 0):

Here a example, but it is for MS SQL Server:

```
USE myBD   -- user DB

DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U'  --carefull here

OPEN tables_cursor
DECLARE @tablename sysname

FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @tablename
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS != -1)
BEGIN
EXEC ('DROP TABLE ' + @tablename)
FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @tablename
END

DEALLOCATE tables_cursor
```